# Problems with multiple 2-digit inputs in Assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I'm fairly new to this PL and I really don't know what I'm doing. It seems my code just takes the first two-digit number and not the second or third.

All I really do is print a prompt asking for a two-digit number, as you can see below. Then it takes the tens and ones digit. Can someone point out what's wrong?

```
;Prompt to enter first number
...

;Gets the first number
mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, num1a
mov edx, 1
int 80h

mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, num1b
mov edx, 1
int 80h

;Prompt to enter Second Number
...

;Gets the second number
mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, num2a
mov edx, 1
int 80h

mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, num2b
;mov edx, 1
int 80h

;Prompt to enter Third Number
...

;Gets the third number
mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, num3a
mov edx, 1
int 80h

mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, num3b
mov edx, 1
int 80h
```

It wont let me put anymore code, but the ... in the codes are all the same.

```
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx. prompt
mov edx, promptLen
int 80h

where:

section .data
prompt db 'Enter a two-digit number: '
promptLen equ $-prompt
```

Comment: Can you post the complete code?

Comment: Don't forget to read any newlines or spaces between the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, increase the size of edx when you are reading the value from the user.

```
  mov eax, 3
  mov ebx, 0
  mov ecx, num1b
  mov edx, 32
  int 80h
```